# windows mobile animation

Tags: windows-mobile

i am new to **Windows Mobile**. Can anyone explain how to use animations in Windows Mobile?

Comment: Can you please add a bit more information? When you say animations, what do you refer to? Showing animated menus/buttons/etc. or showing animated GIFs within your app, or maybe something else?

Comment: i want to use animated controls and pages for my application in windows mobile

Comment: To be clear, do you mean Windows Mobile 6.5 and earlier, or the new Windows Phone 7?  The approach is vastly different between the two.  And what language are you writing in?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to read GIF on WP

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone, animations can enhance your apps by adding movement and interactivity. By animating a background color or applying an animated transform, you can create dramatic screen transitions or provide helpful visual cues. This Quick start shows you how to create basic animations by changing property values and by using key frames.

**Quickstart: Animations for Windows Phone**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206955(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Animatingadoubleproperty